# How to smoothen particle motion in plain JS

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, particles

I would like to add a particle system to a page that generates an appropriate number of particles based on the size of the screen. These particles must never fall outside the screen, but float over the current page.

Unfortunately, I have not been able to generate a nice transition of the particles, which is why I am now looking for help here. At the moment, a new position is simply calculated based on the current position by adjusting the coordinates by the size of the particle.

However, as I do this at a fixed interval, the entire system seems very robotic and not very nice, as the particles virtually teleport back and forth.

I have therefore tried to build the whole thing as HTML and thus tried to incorporate a few transitions with CSS, but that didn't help much either.

How do I set up my code so that the particles use a random image I have predefined and preferably don't need any HTML code but still fly nicely through the entire screen with different directions and generate a suitable number of particles based on the screen size?

I don't want a direction to be predefined and just bounce off the screen.

```js
(() => {
  const SIZE = 10;
  const COUNT = 15;

  let PARTICLES = [];
  let INTERVAL = null;

  const particles = document.getElementById('particles');
  if (!particles) return;

  const handleGeneration = _ => {
    for (let i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
      const particle = document.createElement('span');

      particle.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerHeight) + 'px';
      particle.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerWidth) + 'px';

      particles.appendChild(particle);
      PARTICLES.push(particle);
    }
  };

  const handleMovement = _ => {
    const parseRandom = _ => {
      const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

      switch (random) {
        case 1:
          return SIZE;
        case 2:
          return -SIZE;
        default:
          return random;
      }
    };

    INTERVAL = setInterval(_ => {
      PARTICLES.forEach((particle, index) => {
        let top = parseInt(particle.style.top);
        let left = parseInt(particle.style.left);

        let directionTop = parseRandom();
        let directionLeft = parseRandom();

        if (top + directionTop < 0)
          directionTop = SIZE;
        else if (top + directionTop >= window.innerWidth - SIZE)
          directionTop = -SIZE;

        if (left + directionLeft < 0)
          directionLeft = SIZE;
        else if (left + directionLeft >= window.innerWidth - SIZE)
          directionLeft = -SIZE;

        particle.style.top = top + directionTop + 'px';
        particle.style.left = left + directionLeft + 'px';
      });
    }, 125);
  };

  const handleResize = _ => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', _ => {
      PARTICLES.forEach(particle => particle.remove());
      PARTICLES = [];
      clearInterval(INTERVAL);

      handleGeneration();
      handleMovement();
    });

    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
  };

  handleResize();

})();
```

```css
#particles {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: .25;
 }

#particles span {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  /* mask-repeat: no-repeat; */
  /* mask-size: contain; */
  /* mask-position: center; */
  /* mask-image: url('../../Icons/square.svg'); */
  transition: top 250ms linear, left 250ms linear;
}
  
#particles span:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}

#particles span:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="particles"></div>
```

Comment: Instead of using `setInterval` for animation take a look at [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: Primarily, the issue is that you need to make each particle move in a given direction for more than just one cycle of your loop, by remembering which way it should be going and for how long. You're also updating each particle on every loop, but loops can be slowed down or even stopped when the tab isn't active. If you don't mind the particles slowing or stopping in that time, that's fine, but if not you'd want to use a time-based approach instead (e.g.: remember the time of the last update, then look how long it's been, then adjust for how far the particle should have moved in that time). ...

Comment: ... Using `requestAnimationFrame` may also be useful, particularly if you do the time-based approach I mentioned. But again: You'll get a much smoother animation even if you just have each particle going a given direction for 5 or 10 loops before changing course. (Or having it keep going the same direction until it hits a wall.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it best to use **Math.sin()** or **Math.cos()** to make objects move smoothly.

```js
let amount = window.innerWidth * window.innerHeight / 5000;
let myarray = [];
let randomization = 5, k1, k2;
for(i = 0; i < amount; i ++){
    let square = document.createElement("div");
    square.id = "id" + i;
    square.style.width = square.style.height = "10px";
    square.style.position = "absolute";
    square.style.background = "rgb(" + Math.floor(256 * Math.random()) + ", " + Math.floor(256 * Math.random()) + ", " + Math.floor(256 * Math.random()) + ")";
    document.body.append(square);
    for(j = 0; j < randomization; j ++){
        myarray.push(Math.random());
        myarray.push(Math.random());
    }
}
let x, y;
let t = 10000;
setInterval(function(){
    for(i = 0; i < amount; i ++){
        k1 = k2 = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < randomization; j ++){
            k1 += Math.sin(t / (100 + 200 * myarray[(i * randomization + j) * 2]));
            k2 += Math.sin(t / (100 + 200 * myarray[(i * randomization + j) * 2 + 1]));
        }
        x = window.innerWidth / 2 + window.innerWidth / 2 / randomization * k1;
        y = window.innerHeight / 2 + window.innerHeight / 2 / randomization * k2;
        document.getElementById("id" + i).style.left = x + "px";
        document.getElementById("id" + i).style.top = y + "px";
    }
    t ++;
}, 20);
```

Comment: I really like this approach. Can you please add a short explanation to explain what exactly is happening? What would need to be adjusted here so that the particles are available across the entire area but can also change direction beforehand?

Comment: I've modified the application a little. Now movements are available over the entire area and the number of particles depends directly on the size of the window. In the previous version, each individual particle performed a sinusoidal motion, now the trajectory of the particles has become more complex.

Comment: I've managed to create a great solution based on your code which you can see https://jsfiddle.net/2gv1fL65/2/. Thank you very much for your time and effort.

Comment: I would also like to offer a smooth effect - particles that chase the mouse cursor. At rest, they rotate orderly around the cursor, and when it moves, they catch up with it and at the same time move randomly. Having caught up with the cursor, they again gradually move to the correct circle around the cursor:  [race-for-the-cursor](https://github.com/mysynthesizer/troh-tibidoh/blob/main/race-for-the-cursor.html) | [race for the cursor](https://mysynthesizer.github.io/troh-tibidoh/race-for-the-cursor.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think this version looks pretty good.

Each time slice, I set the target position for one of the particles to a point on the window edge, and let CSS transitions do all the relative motion.

New targets for each particle are chosen to ensure that they are far enough away from the old target to get the particles crossing  a significant part of the window.

```js
(() => {
  const SIZE = 10;
  const COUNT = 15;

  let PARTICLES = [];
  let DIRS = [];
  let INTERVAL = null;

  const particles = document.getElementById('particles');
  if (!particles) return;

  const handleGeneration = _ => {
    for (let i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
      const particle = document.createElement('span');

      particle.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerHeight) + 'px';
      particle.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerWidth) + 'px';

      particles.appendChild(particle);
      PARTICLES.push(particle);
      DIRS.push(Math.random());
    }
  };

  let cur=0;
  const handleMovement = _ => {
    INTERVAL = setInterval(_ => {
      cur = (cur+1)%PARTICLES.length;
      let dir = DIRS[cur] + Math.random()*0.5 + 0.25;
      dir -= Math.floor(dir);
      DIRS[cur] = dir;
      let dx = Math.sin(dir*Math.PI*2);
      let dy = Math.cos(dir*Math.PI*2);
      let fac = 0.5/Math.max(Math.abs(dx), Math.abs(dy));
      let x = window.innerWidth * (0.5 + dx*fac);
      let y = window.innerHeight * (0.5 + dy*fac);

      particle = PARTICLES[cur];
      particle.style.top = String(y-SIZE*0.5) + 'px';
      particle.style.left = String(x-SIZE*0.5) + 'px';
    }, 1750/PARTICLES.length);
  };

  const handleResize = _ => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', _ => {
      PARTICLES.forEach(particle => particle.remove());
      PARTICLES = [];
      clearInterval(INTERVAL);

      handleGeneration();
      handleMovement();
    });

    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
  };

  handleResize();

})();
```

```css
#particles {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: .25;
 }

#particles span {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  /* mask-repeat: no-repeat; */
  /* mask-size: contain; */
  /* mask-position: center; */
  /* mask-image: url('../../Icons/square.svg'); */
  transition: top 2s linear, left 2s linear;
}
  
#particles span:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}

#particles span:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="particles"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Matt for this approach. However, it seems that the particles do not float over the page with deviations, but merely follow a direction which is changed after a certain period of time. How do I get this effect, as if the particles are carried by the wind, so that they really float through the area?

Comment: Ah, your question doesn't say anything about looking like they're being carried by the wind.  That would be a completely different effect.

Comment: I see that there was a certain miscommunication on my part.